# How much must the edge length (side) of the cube decrease from $20$cm to reduce the volume by $12$cm$^3$

Tags: calculus

I have a cube, and the edge length (side) is $20$cm so the volume is $V=20^3=8000$cm$^3$

They ask:

How much must the edge length (side) of the cube decrease from $20$cm to reduce the volume by $12$cm$^3$

Well I use that 
$$\displaystyle\frac{dV}{ds} \approx \frac{\Delta V}{\Delta s}$$
and
$$V=s^3$$

So

$$\displaystyle\frac{dV}{ds}=3s^2$$

Now I calculate

$3s^2 \approx \displaystyle\frac{12}{\Delta s}$ and put $20$ into $s$, $3  \cdot 20^2=1200$

$$1200 \cdot \Delta s\approx 12$$

$$\Delta s \approx \displaystyle\frac{12}{1200}=0,01$$

Am I correct?

Comment: If you don't give a bound for the error, any aproximation is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct.  To verify this, simply calculate the volume when the side length has gone down to 11.99 (12-.01).  As you can see, 11.99^3 is approximately 7988.  This is the required result, and so your answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

If you write
$$(20-x)^3=8000-12=7988$$
this equation can be solved symbolically:
$$x=20-\sqrt[3]{7988}$$

Now you can take the approximation as precise as you need.